# Is it legal to sell a custom element that provides a Technic pin connection?

Tags: technic

I'm wondering if it would be legal to produce a custom piece for Lego Technic and sell it? The piece features 4 compatible connection holes for Technic pins. From what I've researched in the Lego Technic patents, the claim (in the first sentence of each patent) applies to "sets" not individual parts. Here are the patents:

- https://www.google.com.gi/patents/US5964635
- http://www.google.com/patents/US6736691

Does anyone know if there are specific patents covering the pin hole system?

Note: I would of course make sure to use my own designs and not copyright infringe on any of their trademarks regarding packaging, marketing etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, and I recommend you consult one before you start dropping money on injection molds, but as far as I know this should be fine. [SBrick](https://www.sbrick.com/) definitely already does this:

[image: SBrick photo]

In most jurisdictions, [patents have a term of 20 years or less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_of_patent#Jurisdiction). The Technic pin connection dates back to Expert Builder in 1977, so it is not patent encumbered at this point.

The two patents that you linked to from the late 1990s appear to be for ZNAP, which uses a different connection system:

[image: ZNAP Connection photo]

Comment: Many companies with LEGO-like products seem to get away with simply stating "compatible" on the box. They don't mention LEGO but everyone knows what this toy is compatible with.

Comment: Thanks jncraton. That makes things cleaer. I will consulate a lawyer before investing any money into it. If by chance you know where to find the patent from 1977 it would be much appreciated! I can't seem to find it.